# set ajax result to global variable php

Tags: php, ajax, variables

how to set ajax result to global variable PHP

This is index.php Code

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script> 
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() 
        { 
            function getSession()
            {
                $.post("getSession.php", { }, 
                        function(result){
                            $("#div1").text(result);                
                        }
                    );
            }

            setInterval(getSession, 1000);   // 1000 = 1 second
            getSession();
        } 
    ); 
</script>
<body>
<div id="div1"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

And this is getSession.php Code

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION["time"] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

echo $_SESSION["time"];
?>
```

how to set `<div id="div1"></div>` to global variable php like

```
$answer = <div id="div1"></div>
```

Or how to set ajax result to global variable PHP

Comment: why would you like to use global when you can use session variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible. You can't assign javascript results to server side code.
You can make assignments on the server when the ajax request executes on the server though.

A straight JavaScript variable to PHP variable assignment is not possible

Answer (score 0):

Global variables need to be set when the preprocessor (PHP) parses the PHP file. You can send variables and values to PHP script, but only after the main page has been parsed and the script has been executed.

You can have an AJAX call made to a PHP script, and have the script return a variable/value pair as JSON data and have that data managed.

Example: `page1.php` loads up with your JavaScript. AJAX request sent to `page2.php`; `page2.php` processes the request, then spits out an answer as JSON data. JSON data is parsed by `page1.php` and data is pushed in the `div1` `<div>`.

Comment: Please , Can You write example full Code for me ? ThankYou.

Comment: I can point you in the right direction. http://www.cleverweb.nl/php/jquery-ajax-call-tutorial/

Answer (score -1):

Lets say

```
var wanted = whatever....;
windows.wanted = wanted ;
```

try it

Comment: You want to give your answer a bit of explanation?  It's hard to understand what you're suggesting.  Plus I'm pretty sure you mean `window.wanted`.